# Passing a Call without the Params to a Twirl template

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0, twirl

In Play Framework (v 2.3.7) (scala 2.11.5) I wish to pass a Call to a twirl template but I won't be able to calculate the params until after the template loads.

The use case is pagination on a table (with constraints and user defined search options). I want to pass a single call to the template and have it "do the math" (much as I'm not a fan of "programming" in a template - I've chosen to keep HTML generation out of direct scala code -- not sure yet if that is a great decision or not...)

The Call will be similar to this:

```
@routes.AController.list(constraint.id, pageNumber, pageLength)
```

The args are Long, Int, Int in case that is relevant.

I believe what I need is referred to as a partial function? (I could be way off base here)

How do I pass this to say:

```
pagination.scala.html
```

And how would I subsequently call it inside the twirl template?

PS: I have no problems passing fully formed augments to templates -- I just want to wipe the arguments off the argument being passed (man that IS confusing...) and generate those at a later moment in time. Failing that I would have to pass a minimum of four arguments up front which gets ugly really fast.

*Of course I wish to make this generic enough to be reusable but I think I can handle that once I understand the mechanics of how to pass the initial augment.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that latest moment for generating pagination URIs is your view or maybe even better controller's action. Keep in mind that reverse routing in Play is type-save, so you would need to use some kind of reflection to generate *generic* links from level of the `pagination.scala.html` partial.

Instead you can prepare let's say a `List` of `String`s in your controller and pass this to your pagination partial so it can render the typical pagination without any knowledge about the Call for given action.

Note: I like to create own `PaginateUtil` class which contains such fields like `numberOfPages`, `currentPage`, `currentItems` etc. and then passing it whole to the view, to make manipulation in it as small as possible.

Comment: I already have pagination working (from within the twirl template space), along with constraints and user definable search -- all I want to do now is put this into a more concise and reusable format.